# Trying to install apache guacamole on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, libraries

I'm trying to install apache guacamole (v0.9.13) on ubuntu server 14.04 (trusty) but I'm having trouble building the server part. when I try to run `make` I get:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/guacamole/0.9.13/src/guacenc'
  CCLD     guacenc
libtool:   error: cannot find the library '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.la' or unhandled argument '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.la'
```

I Found [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GUACAMOLE-246) which said to disable `guacenc` by doing:

```
./configure --disable-guacenc
```

Which allows me to then successfully run `make` but I get the following errors when I run `make install`:

```
libtool: warning: relinking 'libguac-client-rdp.la'
libtool: install: (cd /home/ubuntu/guacamole/0.9.13/src/protocols/rdp; /bin/bash "/home/ubuntu/guacamole/0.9.13/libtool"  --silent --tag CC --mode=relink gcc -std=gnu99 -Werror -Wall -Iinclude -I../../../src/common -I../../../src/common-ssh -I../../../src/libguac -g -O2 -version-info 0:0:0 -lcairo -lpthread -lfreerdp-core -lfreerdp-cache -lfreerdp-channels -lfreerdp-utils -lfreerdp-codec -o libguac-client-rdp.la -rpath /usr/local/lib libguac_client_rdp_la-audio_input.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-client.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-dvc.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-error.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-input.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-keyboard.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-ptr_string.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-rdp.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-rdp_bitmap.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-rdp_cliprdr.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-rdp_color.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-rdp_disp.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-rdp_fs.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-rdp_gdi.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-rdp_glyph.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-rdp_keymap.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-rdp_print_job.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-rdp_pointer.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-rdp_rail.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-rdp_settings.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-rdp_stream.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-rdp_svc.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-resolution.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-unicode.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-user.lo compat/libguac_client_rdp_la-winpr-stream.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-sftp.lo libguac_client_rdp_la-_generated_keymaps.lo ../../../src/common/libguac_common.la ../../../src/libguac/libguac.la ../../../src/common-ssh/libguac_common_ssh.la )
/bin/grep: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.la: No such file or directory
/bin/sed: can't read /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.la: No such file or directory
libtool:   error: '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.la' is not a valid libtool archive
libtool:   error: error: relink 'libguac-client-rdp.la' with the above command before installing it
```

I've been faffing about with `libjpeg` stuff but nothing there has worked.

And now I'm stuck, I'm not sure what to try next.

EDIT: output of `apt list --installed | grep libjpeg`:

```
libjpeg-dev/trusty,now 8c-2ubuntu8 amd64 [installed]
libjpeg-turbo8/trusty,now 1.3.0-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libjpeg-turbo8-dev/trusty,now 1.3.0-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libjpeg8/trusty,now 8c-2ubuntu8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libjpeg8-dev/trusty,now 8c-2ubuntu8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to build the project by:

1. removing all `libjpeg` stuff
2. installing `libjpeg62-dev`
3. running `./configure --disable-guacenc`

I tried installing the older version of `libjpeg` on the off chance it would work, and it did; I still had to disable `guacenc` though.